# Ansible global fail message when a task has failed on all hosts

Tags: ansible

I need a fail message when a task has failed on all hosts.
For example:

```
- ios_facts:
    gather_subset: min
  failed_when: "{{ ansible_net_hostname }} contains 123"
```

where all of the hostnames contains 123 so it triggers a fail task

```
- fail:
    msg: all of the hostnames contains 123
  when: xxxxx
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, given the inventory for testing

```yaml
shell> cat hosts
host1 ansible_net_hostname=host_123_A
host2 ansible_net_hostname=host_123_B
host3 ansible_net_hostname=host_123_C
```

The play below shows how to find the lists

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: ansible_net_hostname
    - debug:
        msg: |
          All names: {{ _names }}
          Search names: {{ _search }}
      vars:
        _names: "{{ hostvars|json_query('*.ansible_net_hostname') }}"
        _search: "{{ _names|select('search', '123')|list }}"
      run_once: true
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [debug] ***********************************************************
ok: [host1] => 
  ansible_net_hostname: host_123_A
ok: [host2] => 
  ansible_net_hostname: host_123_B
ok: [host3] => 
  ansible_net_hostname: host_123_C

TASK [debug] ***********************************************************
ok: [host1] => 
  msg: |-
    All names: ['host_123_A', 'host_123_B', 'host_123_C']
    Search names: ['host_123_A', 'host_123_B', 'host_123_C']
```

Compare the length of the lists

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: all of the hostnames contains 123
      vars:
        _names: "{{ hostvars|json_query('*.ansible_net_hostname') }}"
        _search: "{{ _names|select('search', '123')|list }}"
      when: _names|length == _search|length
      run_once: true
```

---

<sup>(Credit @Zeitounator for pointing to this option.)</sup>

The query above works if you target all hosts in the inventory. If you'd like to target a group of hosts use the special variable [*ansible_play_hosts_all*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#special-variables) and [*extract*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#selecting-values-from-arrays-or-hashtables) the variables from the *hostvars*. For example, given the inventory

```yaml
shell> cat hosts
[test_123]
host[0001:1024]

[test_123:vars]
ansible_net_hostname=host_123_A
```

The play

```yaml
- hosts: test_123
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: |
          All names: {{ _names|length }}
          Search names: {{ _search|length }}
      vars:
        _names: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all|
                    map('extract', hostvars, 'ansible_net_hostname')|
                    list }}"
        _search: "{{ _names|select('search', '123')|list }}"
      run_once: true
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [debug] *****************************************************
ok: [host0001] => 
  msg: |-
    All names: 1024
    Search names: 1024
```

To evaluate the condition compare the length of the lists as before.

Comment: Thank you ! I have another case where I need to select the facts that are blank, how could I make this to work ? `_search: "{{ _names|select('search', '')|list }}"`

Comment: I think OP wants to know if all hostnames **in the host play loop** pass the test or not. Your answer is looking at the entire inventory regardless of the current targets in play.

Comment: @raw other questions go in a new post, or at the very least in an edit to your current question, not in a comment. Thanks.

Comment: @Zeitounator: There are no other hosts in *hostvars* except all hosts in the play.

Comment: @VladimirBotka I have to disagree on this last one: https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/3a3ac34b96ccd49998523adf7da3e1cd  as you will see I created a play targetting a specific group and hostvars yet contains all entries for all targets in the entire inventory. Meanwhile I apparently misinterpreted from the question as that seem to do the job anyway ;)

Comment: @Zeitounator. I see. I updated the answer. Thank you.